# How to return elements of array matching criteria in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongodb and I'm still trying to wrap my head around queries so forgive me if my question is too simple or have been answered elsewhere.

I have a collection like the one below

```
[
{"_id":1,
"data" :[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":3},{"a":2,"b":3},{"a":4,"b":1}]
},
{"_id":2,
"data" :[{"a":3,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":4},{"a":5,"b":3},{"a":7,"b":1}]
}
]
```

How can I write a query that looks inside the data array of the first document and returns all elements where "a" is equal to one.

Something like this is the expected output:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":3}]
```

This is my current attempt

```
db.myCollection.find({_id:1},{data: {$elemMatch: {a : 1}}})
```

But this gives me

```
{"_id": 1, "data":
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"b":3}]
}
```

I don't need or want anything other than the results in "data".

Can someone give me a hand?

I'd also appreciate any pointers for sifting through an array in a document for elements matching more general conditions on a single document (ie for the example above finding the documents where a+b < 5, a > b, a>1 and b>2, a >3 or b<1, etc.)

Edit: I'm using mongodb version 4.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$filter` is the general purpose way to, well, filter arrays inside of docs.   Expanding your input set to give a little more context and variety:

```
var r =
[
 {
     "_id": 0,
     "other":6,
     "data" :[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"X"},
              {"a":1,"b":3,"c":"Y"},
              {"a":2,"b":3,"c":"Q"},
              {"a":4,"b":1,"c":"Z"}]
 },
 {
     "_id": 1,
     "other":7,
     "data" :[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":"A"},
              {"a":1,"b":3,"c":"B"},
              {"a":7,"b":7,"c":"C"},
              {"a":1,"b":8,"c":"D"}]
 }
];
db.foo.insert(r);
```

Then these two pipelines demo the versatility of `$filter`:

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {_id:false,
            // Notice input is $data and output project is data; this                     
            // means overwrite the old data array with the filtered array.                 
            // Also:  The double dollar is how we reference the "as"                      
            // variable.  Single dollar variables refer to the fields                     
            // of the incoming doc; we show how to use $other in this                     
            // example.   $other remains constant for the doc as $filter
            // marches down the $data array:                                                                 
            data: {$filter: {
                input: "$data",
                as: "z",
                cond: { $lt: [ {$add:["$$z.a","$$z.b"]} , "$other" ]}
            }}
    }}
                       ]);


c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {_id:true,
            data: {$filter: {
                input: "$data",
                as: "z",
                cond: { $or: [ {$gt:["$$z.a",3]}, {$lt:["$$z.b",7]} ] }
            }}
    }}
                       ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have almost everything, you just forget the projection at end:

```
db.myCollection.find({_id:1},{data: {$elemMatch: {a : 1}}}, {_id: 0, data: 1})
```